# MQ message endpoint gets paused automatically-IBM websphere

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-7, mq, message-driven-bean

The configured MQ message endpoints get paused automatic many times and we had to keep eye-on and then resume it manually.
Any idea on why it gets auto-paused? 
Is the receiver channel gets full with MQ messages ?

MQ version 6 is being used currently in our application to communicate with external system through messages.Due to this issue, the feature which uses that listener does not provide the service intermittently until we manual resume the endpoints.

IBM Websphere Console: Application->Application Types->Websphere Enterprise Applications-> WC Comm01->Runtime Tab->Manage Message Endpoints.

Comment: By 'end points' do you mean an MQ channel, perhaps a receiver channel? When you see it in paused state where do you see this, is it the channel status? What do you do to resume the endpoints? What command do you issue to achieve this? With this information I will be able to answer your question.

Comment: This is the endpoint I am making it resume in IBM Websphere Console: Application->Application Types->Websphere Enterprise Applications-> WC Comm01->Runtime Tab->Manage Message Endpoints. We are using Gift card MQ service to recieve information from external system through these listeners,which are getting paused

Answer (score 4):

The message endpoint is being paused because there was an error in processing the MDB and the behaviour of pausing(stopping) the endpoint is what has been configured on the activation specification. Have a look at this page: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/umj_pasm_advprops.html?lang=en for details on the advanced settings. The properties you are interested in is the "Stop endpoint if message delivery fails" and "Number of sequential message delivery failures before suspending endpoint".

So you could turn off the "Stop endpoint if message delivery fails" and this would stop your message endpoint from auto-pausing. However, you will still have message delivery failures and the message delivery will be retried to the MDB. I would check the application server logs to see what the error is in your MDB and fix that issue (if you can). You can then determine whether you want to the endpoint to auto-pause or maybe configure it so it auto-pauses but only after a larger number of sequential failures than what is currently configured.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the queue manager errors logs for more information.  There is more to this issue than you are telling us right now.
2. Describe the flow, like QA:aliasq -> QR:remoteq -> XQ:xmitq -> CH:channel.name/type